# Skipping white space in text file with ifstream?

Tags: c++, space, ifstream

I have a C++ code that reads a text file with a list of people's names, addresses, city, state, etc. After each person's information, there is a blank line in the file before the next person's information. My program is set on a while loop that reads all the information and then prints it to the screen before it's supposed to start the loop again. The problem is that it counts the blank line after the first person's information as the end of the file, and the loop stops. How can I get ifstream to ignore this blank line and continue to the next set of information?

Comment: We need to see code.

Answer (score 0):

use getline, and EOF as termination point.